# Youtube URL in Windows Phone 8

Tags: youtube, windows-phone-8

How do I launch the Youtube app in Windows Phone 8 without going to the browser. Basically I am currently using the following code and it takes me to the default browser instead of opening up the Youtube app:

```
Dim webBrowserTask As New WebBrowserTask()
webBrowserTask.Uri = New Uri("http://www.youtube.com/embed/3aP3KBsh3Y8",UriKind.Absolute)
webBrowserTask.Show()
```

I want to be able to launch the Youtube app directly. So far I haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slightly better way. Use WebBrowserTask but give it URL in this format

```
String.Format("vnd.youtube:{0}?vndapp=youtube",youTubeId)
```

where youTubeId is the ID of the youtube video (3aP3KBsh3Y8 in your case)