# I want to open Youtube URL in my Win-phone's app

Tags: c#, youtube, windows-phone

I have Youtube link with me , and i want to open that video in my windows phone's application
I tried MediaElement but its not playing FLV content waht are my Alternatives can anyone please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this:

```
WebBrowserTask wbTask= new WebBrowserTask();
wbTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/../....");
wbTask.Show();
```

Also refer this question>>

[Youtube URL in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670120/youtube-url-in-windows-phone-8)

Hope its helpful.

Comment: i know that ,, but i dont want a web browser to open that url ,, i want to play the video ,, on the very same page :( like a normal video

Comment: means you want to just link youtube video to your page?

Comment: yeah .. i have d url ohk ,, so when i click play button the video would play in a specified area on my page OR on some sort of a player in next redirected page ( BUT NOT on webbrowser )

Comment: @Ankit refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670120/youtube-url-in-windows-phone-8 might helpful to you.

Comment: ,, it didn't work :/ have a look at Google.Gdata.Youtube API .. its helpfull but still my mission is not accomplished ( there's no YouTube Class in that API :( ,, check it ,, might you get something :/